# not applicable for the arguments (void) error

Tags: java

Hi I am working on a project and i get an error which I cant solve. The error message from the Eclipse program is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       The method add(String) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (void)
>       The method add(String) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (void)
>       ham cannot be resolved

```
at PizzaChoice.main(PizzaChoice.java:50)
```

Thats the code:

```
        System.out.print("\nDo you want thick base?");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    choice = input.charAt(0);
    if (choice == 'y'){
        pizza.thick.setCost(8.75);
        pizza.thick.getType();
        l.add(pizza.thick.getType());
        c.add((double) pizza.thick.getCost());
        totalPizzaBasePrice = totalPizzaBasePrice + pizza.thick.getCost();
```

Comment: What are the return types of `pizza.thick.getType()` and `pizza.thick.getCost()`?

Comment: why do you have `pizza.thick.getType();` on its own line? should it be `setType()`?

Comment: Its in the PizzaBase.java

Comment: not really sure, im not good in java :(

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? In which case select "getType" and hit F3. What code is there?
If not, try to find out where "ham" is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will help you figure it out, `ArrayList.add` below would take any object but I'm not passing it anything since the expression `new Object().wait()` will evaluate to void (nothing is returned by wait), that is why the compiler complaints (The method add(Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (void))

```
new ArrayList<>().add(new Object().wait());
```

check the signature of the methods `pizza.thick.getType()` and `pizza.thick.getCost()`  and see which returns void e.g. `public void getType().....`

Answer (score 1):

Either getType() or getCost() return type is void.